# how to create color.xml create programmatically in android?

Tags: android

I am new android devloper.I have change color runtime so i want to create color.xml in java programming.i have hint to create this.i have declare all color.java in android

Answer (score 1):

You cannot generate resource files or change the contents of existing resource files at runtime.

If you want to change colors at runtime, you will need to use an alternate method.